# Can I clone a partition inside the same hard drive

Tags: partitioning, backup, partition-recovery

I'm rescueing a hard drive and I already have a backup of the partition, now I wish to have a copy of this backup in order to safely work with it, problem is that I only have the hard drive where lays the backup. The hard drive is 1 tera containing only my backup on a 500 GB partition so there're still 500 GB free and unpartitioned.

In fewer words I need to clone /dev/sdX1 to /dev/sdX2 but I'm not sure how to reach this.

¿Do I have to create /dev/sdX2 and then do:

dd if=/dev/sdX1 of= /dev/sdX2

?

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what you need to do.

To clone a hard drive, you essentially need to:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY
```

And to clone a partition, as in your  case, you need to:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX1 of=/dev/sdX2
```

And you also need to make sure that none of the partitions are mounted.

Comment: Should I precise that target partition must be equal or bigger than source partition and preferably located after source?

Or is it that source partition cannot be overwritten?

Comment: @LerianAcosenossa partitions themselves do not have metadata, so the new (target) partition must be big enough to contain all the data inside the source partition. This does not necessarily mean that you can do it with a smaller target partition, because the data can be fragmented in the source partition and there can be data at the end, even if the partition is half-empty. So safest option is to have an equal or bigger partition. And doesn't matter if the partition is located before or after source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. not that by cloning /dev/sdx? rather then /dev/sdx you will loose boot information - while you can recover all the files, you may have difficulty in booting from the cloned partition.

You can use dd to copy block devices, but I prefer ddrescue which tries harder and gives a progress report. You can get a ddrescue package for most common distros - eg gnuddrescue for Ubuntu.